# unity editor not responding after build

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I have a very old project with a lot of code. So each time after apk build is finished the editor starting to not respond and I need to restart him.
Because there is a lot of plugins and old code in it, I don't know where to start finding that bad code which cause troubles.

Comment: Start with the editor log (Console view / right click on tab / Open Editor Log)

Comment: nothing in it, for example the last stroke will be
*** Cancelled 'Build.Player.AndroidPlayer' in 116 seconds and after that unity is not responding

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you can choose one scene and create prefabs of all top level objects in that scene. Then inside Project window right click on the prefabs and choose "Select Dependencies", then Unity will select all other objects in the Project assets and while all those objects are still selected again right click on any of them and choose "Export Package..." This might take a while and Unity may look stuck but wait for it to generate the list of all those objects and show you a new export window. Once the export window is show you can choose to save the results as a unitypackage file. Create a new Unity project and import that unitypackage and test the scene and make a new build. This way you should be able to strip down the large project into pieces until you find where it causes the problem.